simr Failing to Run, "observed power calculation"
I am analyzing simulated delay-discounting data. The response variable is reaction time in milliseconds. K is the scaling factor describing how much value is affected by delay. College Year is from 1-4. ImpulseTotal is the participant's level of impulsivity.
The model is as follows.
simdata_lmer <- 
  lme4::lmer(
  RT_MS ~ ImpulseTotal * CollegeYr + (1|k), 
  simdata_R2_F2
)

which returns
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

I then ran this power curve.
powerC <- simr::powerCurve(
  fit = simdata_lmer, 
  test = fixed("complexity"), 
  along = "ImpulseTotal",  
  breaks = c(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350)
)

After posting many warning messages about the singular fit, it generates this message.
In observedPowerWarning(sim) :
  This appears to be an "observed power" calculation

Viewing powerC produces these results.
> powerC
Power for predictor 'complexity', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of ImpulseTotal:
  74.35:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 1350 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows
     NA:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 2700 rows

Time elapsed: 0 h 3 m 43 s

Please advise.

It sounds like there are issues with the main model that need to be remediated before running what I guess is a post-hoc power calculation.

The "observed power" warning is not related to the problems in results. You always get that warning when you use actual data instead of using the makeLmer or makeGlmer function. Singular fit is often due to very low random effect variance. Maybe post the model ouput?

It also appears you test the power for a fixed predictor that is not in the model code as predictor...?
